# Event Listener inside class - automatically use

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

i want to change my slider on my site to object. I almost did (I think so), but I have one problem with EventListener. The case is, when I reload the page, viewport is automatically scrolled down and buttons which I want to bind aren't working.

```
class Scroller {
    constructor() {
        this.button = document.querySelectorAll(".site-part");
        this.conntactButton = document.querySelector(".slider button");
        this.navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar-element");
        this.differenceY = this.getNavbarHeight(this.navbar);
        this.isEdge = this.isEdge();
        this.sections = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll-to');
        this.contactSection = document.querySelector('.contact');

        this.addScroll();
    }

    isEdge() {
        if (/Edge/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    getNavbarHeight(element) {
        if (screen.width < 768) {
            return 60;
        } else {
            return element.getBoundingClientRect().height;
        }
    }

    getPosition(element) {
        return Math.ceil(element.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY - this.differenceY);
    }

    scroll(element) {
        window.scrollTo({
            behavior: 'smooth',
            top: this.getPosition(element),
        });
    }

    addScroll() {
        // for (let i = 0; i < this.button.length; i++) {
        //     this.button[i].addEventListener('click', this.scroll(this.sections[i]));
        // }
        this.conntactButton.addEventListener('click', this.scroll(this.contactSection))
    }

}
```

Comment: `this.conntactButton.addEventListener('click', this.scroll(this.contactSection))` calls `this.scroll` immediately and passes it's return value `undefined` to `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

The event listener for 'contact' button lost the scope. You need to use bind() in the constructor. Put below line inside of constructor(): 
    this.contactButton = this.contactButton.bind(this); 
I think it should work. Try it and let me know if that works or not.

Comment: If you meant to put it in constructor() under function `this.addScroll(); this.contactButton = this.contactButton.bind(this);`, it didnt work unfortunately.

Comment: I see you found the solution now.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, all I need to do was use arrow function:

```
    addScroll() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.button.length; i++) {
            this.button[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
                this.scroll(this.sections[i]);
            });
        }
        this.conntactButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            this.scroll(this.contactSection);
        });
    }
```

is there any other way to make that work?

Comment: `.bind`: `this.conntactButton.addEventListener('click', this.scrol(...).bind(this))`